# Xcode error: Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation. Failed to create promise

Tags: ios, react-native

I just got a company repo built with React Native CLI, after running the iOS project I got a dialogue alert box with

> **Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.** Failed
> to create promise.

On clicking the Details button, I saw the following error in the an issue window (terminal)

```
   Details

Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.
Domain: IXErrorDomain
Code: 2
Failure Reason: Failed to create promise.
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-04-23 06:42:07 +0000";
    FunctionName = "+[IXPlaceholder _placeholderForBundle:client:withParent:installType:metadata:placeholderType:mayBeDeltaPackage:error:]";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    SimCallingSelector = "installApplication:withOptions:error:";
    SourceFileLine = 884;
}
--
Failed to set app extension placeholders for com.companyname.[applicationname]
Domain: IXErrorDomain
Code: 2
Failure Reason: Failed to create promise.
User Info: {
    FunctionName = "+[IXPlaceholder _placeholderForBundle:client:withParent:installType:metadata:placeholderType:mayBeDeltaPackage:error:]";
    SourceFileLine = 884;
}
--
Attempted to set app extension placeholder promise with bundle ID ccom.companyname.[applicationname] that does not match required prefix of com.companyname.[applicationname]. for parent
Domain: IXErrorDomain
Code: 8
Failure Reason: Mismatched bundle IDs.
User Info: {
    FunctionName = "-[IXPlaceholder setAppExtensionPlaceholderPromises:error:]";
    SourceFileLine = 1392;
}
--
...
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.3.1 (Build 22E261)
Xcode 14.3 (21812) (Build 14E222b)
Timestamp: 2023-04-23T07:42:07+01:00
```

Comment: Add code highlight , please. 
It is complicated to understand where is an error message and where is your message.

Comment: @ZufarSunagatov, I hope this edit helps now, sorry I am new to asking questions on stack overflow

Comment: @David Are you able to resolve this issue in simulator ?

Comment: @David any update ?